# iOS iPhone looking for a fast logging of timestamped integers to data file implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, logging, file-io

I'm looking for suggestions/implementations of how to create a comma separated log file on an iPhone when my data comes at a relatively fast rate (200 times per second). I expect to capture the timestamp and 2-3 integer numbers for each data point. Over a 15 minute period, there would be 15*60*200 = 180,000 rows of data, each one having a timestamp, a few integers and a newline character.

I want to make sure that writing of this data to disk happens in the correct sequential order.

My current implementation has been optimized for data coming in at 1 data point per second, and may not be very efficient for "fast" data. **How can I tweak my code** to make sure that it can run in a background thread without taking too much resources for each write? Alternatively, **is there a fast "log to data file" implementation out there that I can just give numbers to and ask it for a log file at a later point?**

```
   NSString *appDataFile ;
    NSFileHandle *aFileHandle;

-(NSString*)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    appDataFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];
    aFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:appDataFile];
    return appDataFile;
}

//creates a new log file for each app run, or appends to existing log
-(void)writeStringToDataFile:(NSString *)csvLine
{

    if(aFileHandle)
    {
        //telling aFilehandle what file write to
        [aFileHandle truncateFileAtOffset:[aFileHandle seekToEndOfFile]]; //setting aFileHandle to write at the end of the file
        [aFileHandle writeData:[csvLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }else{
        NSData* headers = [@"timestamp,waveform amplitude,score, connection, event\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //clear the old log file
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFileManager* fileManager =  [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[self dataFilePath] error:&error];

        //create CSV headers
        aFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:appDataFile];
        [headers writeToFile:appDataFile atomically:YES];

        aFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:appDataFile];
        //telling aFilehandle what file write to
        [aFileHandle truncateFileAtOffset:[aFileHandle seekToEndOfFile]]; //setting aFileHandle to write at the end of the file
        [aFileHandle writeData:[csvLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

}
```

Comment: How about: store data in memory with a NSArray. And then use a background thread to keep retrieving that data from the NSArray, and write it into the file. That would be easy to implement and maintainance? You can create a queue with first in first out so you will not run out of memory

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion. I currently have a circular array of ~600 data points for data that comes in at 1/sec and implement autosave of this data using array index every 2 minutes. Using a plain array would require too much memory (up to 21 Mb in the case of fast logging)

Answer (score 2):

One obvious change is to remove the needless call to truncate the file for every line you want to write. Just move the handle to the end once when you open the file.

The next round of changes would be to use C code instead of Objective-C. Use `fopen` to open the file. Use `fputs` to write a C-string.

Another place to check is how you build the `csvLine`. Using `stringWithFormat` is slow. Get low level and write each separate value as a C-string using `fputs`. No need for formatting. No need to convert to NSData.

Also take a look at how you do the timestamp. If you convert an `NSDate` to an `NSString` you will waste a lot of time.

Here's the big suggestion - If time is so critical, build a big mutable string in memory and then write the whole thing to a file in one shot when done. This will cut out file I/O during the time critical phase.

Make use of Instruments to find where the true bottlenecks are. Without it you could optimize the wrong code.